# how fast are string operations in Perl? In particular concatenation and assignment

Tags: perl, performance, string

How fast is string concatenation in Perl? Is it linear to the length of the second operand? If so, what conditions need to be met for this operation to be linear? What are the examples on non-linear concatenation time?

And what about string assignment? When and where does the actual copy of the buffer occurs?

What about other operations like substring or simple regexes?

Comment: Sounds like a fun opportunity to try writing some benchmarking tools. Last time I did, I was stunned at how much faster Perl was than many other tools, including 'simple' hand-written C.

Comment: Concatenation is most probably linear to total length. At least when I tried concatenating a 1+MB file while reading it line by line, it was a mess, however join ("", @input) ran reasonably fast. (I didn't know of slurping then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this myself. Concatenation is linear to the length of the second argument but assignment is always linear to the length of the string.

It looks like Perl does not count references for strings but associates a buffer with every variable (reference).

Here are some test results:

Concatenation seems to be constant and entire test is linear:

```
 248ms   my $x; $x .= "a" for 1..2_000_000
 501ms   my $x; $x .= "a" for 1..4_000_000
 967ms   my $x; $x .= "a" for 1..8_000_000
```

`$x = $x . $y` seems to be optimized and uses `$x` buffer in this case:

```
 295ms   my $x; $x = $x . "a" for 1..2_000_000
 592ms   my $x; $x = $x . "a" for 1..4_000_000
1170ms   my $x; $x = $x . "a" for 1..8_000_000
```

Previous optimization seems to be done statically so concatenation in next test is linear to the resulting string length and entire test is quadratic:

```
 233ms   my $x; ${\$x} = ${\$x} . "a" for 1..40_000
 951ms   my $x; ${\$x} = ${\$x} . "a" for 1..80_000
3811ms   my $x; ${\$x} = ${\$x} . "a" for 1..160_000
```

Copying is linear:

```
 186ms   my $x; for (1..50_000) { $x .= "a"; my $y = $x }
 764ms   my $x; for (1..100_000) { $x .= "a"; my $y = $x }
3029ms   my $x; for (1..200_000) { $x .= "a"; my $y = $x }
```

Every copy is linear, reference counting is not used for strings:

```
 545ms   my $x; for (1..50_000) { $x .= "a"; my $y = $x; my $y2 = $x; my $y3 = $x }
2264ms   my $x; for (1..100_000) { $x .= "a"; my $y = $x; my $y2 = $x; my $y3 = $x }
8951ms   my $x; for (1..200_000) { $x .= "a"; my $y = $x; my $y2 = $x; my $y3 = $x }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is really complex question and answer depends on far many factors (architecture, underlying OS, HW, Perl compilation flags, etc.)

To get an idea, you can take a look at internals of perl structures used to represent your variables. Good source is [perlguts illustrated](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/index.html).

If you have specific implementation in mind, try benchmarking your code:

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $a = "Some string";
my @b = map { "Some string to append " x $_ } (1..10);

cmpthese(-1, {
    ( map {+ "concat_$_" => sub { my $c = $a . $b[$_] } } (1..10) )
});
```

The thing above compares operation `my $c = $a . $b` for various length of second argument. From result it can be seen that for this length ranges the operation runs roughly in linear time.

Comment: @cjm - thanks for fixes. I didn't know that it has non-version specific version.

Comment: +1 for perlguts link - thanks. I cannot accept this answer in this form though, because it does not answer the question and is too vague in general. I do not think that underlying OS may have anything to do with the complexity of string concatenation (unless you would go as deep as analyzing malloc complexity which I wouldn't expect here nor you tried to touch).